# Problems on the Cardinality of the Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Problem 1**
>
> For any set $A$, let $B^A$ be the set of all functions mapping $A$ into the set $B=\{0,1\}$. Show that $\left \lvert B^A \right \rvert=\left \lvert\mathscr {P}(A)\right \rvert$ where $\left\lvert S \right \rvert$ means the cardinality of $S$, for any set $S$ and $\mathscr {P}(A)$ denotes the Power Set of $A$.
>
> **Problem 2**
>
> 1. Show that (using the same notation as the above problem) $\mathscr {P}(A)$ has too many elements to be put in an one to one correspondence with $A$.
> 2. Explain why this intuitively means that there are an infinite number of infinite cardinal numbers.
> 3. Is *the set of everything* a logically acceptable concept? Why or why not?

I have only proved the problems for finite $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$. For a proof of Problem 1 when $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$ is finite, we note that for each element $a \in A$ there are only two choices from the set $B$. Hence the total number of such functions will be $2^\left \lvert A \right \rvert=\left \lvert \mathscr {P}(A) \right \rvert$.

But if $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$ is not finite then I don't know how to proceed because the argument that has been given for finite $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$ may not apply to the non-finite $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$.

Similar problem is with Problem 2. For the first part if $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$ is finite then we note that for a bijection to exist between $A$ and $\mathscr P(A)$ then $\left \lvert \mathscr {P}(A) \right \rvert$ must be equal to $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$. But since for finite $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$, it is an integer and for all $\left \lvert A \right \rvert \geq1$ we have $\left \lvert A \right \rvert<2^{\left \lvert A \right \rvert}$, we conclude that for finite $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$ there cannot exist a bijection between $A$ and $\mathscr P(A)$.

But here again the problem is when $\left \lvert A \right \rvert$ is non-finite.

For third part of Problem 2, is the answer simply is that since *everything* is not a well-defined concept, *the set of everything* is not a logically acceptable concept, or is there some more subtle reasoning?

How can the problem be tackled?

Comment: For Problem $1$, are you familiar with [*indicator* (or *characteristic*) functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)? For Problem $2$ you should look at [Cantor’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you very much. Can you look at the part 3 of Problem 2?

Comment: I think that the set of all sets thing was tackled on the site many times before.

Comment: @Brian: This seems to lead to Cantor's paradox, not to Russell's.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: What is meant in the proof of Cantor's Theorem (see the definition of $B$) by $x \in f(x)$? Shouldn't it be $x \in f(A)$?

Comment: @user170039: For that you should look at [Cantor’s paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_paradox) and [Russell’s paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox). Neither is exactly what you want, but they may point you in the right direction, especially the former.

Comment: @Asaf: You’re right; I didn’t read carefully enough.

Comment: @user170039: No, $x\notin f(x)$ is correct. The idea is that the function $f$ associates to each element $x$ of $A$ a subset $f(x)$ of $A$, and $B$ collects the elements of $A$ that are *not* in their associated subsets.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162/why-is-the-set-of-all-sets-a-paradox is a nice thread about Cantor's paradox. See my answer the "more subtle" reasoning (and there is one!)

Comment: @user170039: $f:A\to\wp(A)$, so for each $x\in A$ we have $f(x)\in\wp(A)$ and hence $f(x)\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when we consider the cardinality, we use the concept of a 'bijection'.

So, in problem 1, if you want to show such equality in general case, you should construct explicit or implicit form of bijection between $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $B^{A}$

In problem 2, you should argue by contradiction. Suppose there exists a bijection between two sets, then some contradiction happen.

Suppose $g:A \rightarrow 2^A$, then consider $B=\{x\in A| x\notin g(x)\}$ and note that $B\in 2^A$.

So that, there is $y\in A$ such that $g(y)=B$.

Either $y\in B$ or $y\notin B$, you can easily observe what is contradiction.

Such method used above is called 'Diagonalization'.

Comment: Can you please define one such bijection for infinite sets? I'm stuck in this problem #1 too, thanks! :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for late check. Suppose S be a subset of A, which means S is an element of the power set of A. Then, map this S into the following function : the function g in B^A such that the image of all element in S is 1, otherwise 0. You can easily observe that this function g uniquely characterize A in the power set P(A). If you can't make it sense well, then just prove bijectivity by hand writing!